# Connecting to clients with same LAN IP Range on OpenVPN

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, openvpn

We use OpenVPN under Windows to connect with Remote Desktop to servers in our clients, we share the same LAN subnet of 255.255.255.0, which means we're facing issues since attempting to connect while OpenVPN is on lands us in our internal network computers, we also need simultaneous acess to our own server.

I'm on Windows 10 and am not sure there's much to be done short of changing either one of the subnets, which woudn't be viable for either of us... Is there something I can do to change OpenVPN subnet once it connects, taking in consideration that we do not manage the VPN?

Comment: Can you give an example of ipaddress issue

Comment: Both ours and theirs server at 192.168.1.202, how can I connect to both at the same time? I attempted what is described here: https://serverfault.com/a/1001551/994019, so 'client-nat dnat 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.0' and 'route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0' on config file and it did work, but connections seems very unstable, AnyDesk works flawlesly  but we need simultaneous connection.

Comment: The answer is nuanced and messy.  You are trying to breach a core design rule of IP networks.   There is single correct answer, although it may be partially doable by statically routing individual ip addresses (route 192.168.2.2 255.255.255.255) out the VPN while having the more generic routes on the LAN.

Comment: What are you connecting (browser, apps) ?

Comment: Initially it was an app supposed to connect to a database on their server, but because both servers had the same LAN IP we settled for Remote Desktop Connection on another server

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when the VPN is active, you have in the computer two
network adapters that support the same network range.
I'm assuming that the VPN is not defined as compulsory, meaning that
it allows connections through the other network adapter.

The two network adapters then differ only by their metrics. Usually the
VPN driver ensures that its network adapter will have a lower metric,
so that Windows will always prefer its addresses.

However, nothing prevents you from changing the metrics of any
network adapter in the computer, therefore ensuring that Windows
will choose the one with the lower metric.

Thus, you may create two PowerShell scripts that will set the metrics
of the two adapters, where one sets the VPN as the lower metric,
while the other does the opposite. This will ensure that one or the
other is used by Windows for resolving IP addresses.

Thus solution would be much simpler than just continuously
connecting and disconnecting the VPN.

You would use the following PowerShell commands :

- [Get-NetAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapter?view=windowsserver2022-ps)
- [Set-NetIPInterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/set-netipinterface?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

The commands to use would look like :

```
Get-NetAdapter -Name "Ethernet 2" | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 21
```

Comment: That's a nice workaround but doesn't really solve the issue, I don't even think my "solution" of using client-nat fixes it...

Comment: There aren't too many workarounds, but I think that mine is the easiest.